# Cross-device In-AppPurchases

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

due to the fact that Apple requires at least one auto-renewable subscription or one free subscription for a newsstand app, we changed all monthly subscriptions of our news app to auto-renewable ones while adding newsstand functionality.

When I try to buy one of these subscriptions on device #1 (e.g. my iPad) everything works fine. When I try to buy the same subscription on device #2 (e.g. my iPhone), I get a message from the Store Kit telling me that I am already a subscriber of this certain issue (which is ok as well) but afterwards the process is finished without having bought anything.

Checking the log shows, that the SKPaymentTransactionObserver delegate method paymentQueue:updatedTransactions: first gets a transaction for that product in the state 'SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing' (ok so far) followed by transaction in the state 'SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed'. Having a closer look on the transaction error code and message of the last transaction, the transaction error description says "Cannot connect to iTunes Store'. A second purchase of another product (bought the first time on the second device) works perfectly. Both purchases are done against the sandbox, does anybody has a hint how to address this problem.

Thanks for your help in advance
Michael

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be possible to to purchase the same auto-renewing subscription on multiple devices, instead you should implement restore functionality, and restore on the second device. It's worth noting that the sandbox uses time compression for testing, so a 1 month subscription, will actually auto-renew every 5 minutes or so, and will only renew 5 times in  a day. it's possible the original subscription has expired by the time you try to repurchase for the second time.

Often the sandbox error messages are not useful, the "Couldn't connect to iTunes" is not relevant.

I would suggest reading the whole of this page very carefully, as there are a lot of important details it's easy to miss. The bit about restoring purchases is here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/MakingaPurchase/MakingaPurchase.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH3-SW1

Best of luck

Comment: yes your right p-double you want to Restore the transactions for the particular user